# PHP rename how long

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the status how long does it takes to copy the file.

With the php rename function.

rename($old_dest, $new_dest);

Comment: Is it that difficult to **measure**? ps: it should be almost immediate

Comment: Not possible, and rename operations should take almost no time

Comment: The `rename` command doesn't copy a file; it just, erm, renames it `:)`

Comment: Btw, quite a lot of file system operations are cached, and so how long a thing takes to do is sometimes harder than just timing it. Would you let us know why you need to do this, and then maybe someone can add some extra detail?

Comment: @halfer: what if it moves a file from one partition to another?

Comment: You're right, it _can_ do that - thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rename a file, you have to distinguish two scenarios:

- The old name and the new name are on the same filesystem. In this case, the operating system only needs to modify two directory entries.
- The old name and the new name are on different filesystems. That means that renaming is equivalent to copying and then removing the old file. Therefore, the amount of time it takes will depend on the size of the file.

In either case, the speed will depend on, in roughly descending order:

1. The I/O usage of the system. If thousands of processes modify files in parallel to yours, any filesystem operating will be slow.
2. The in-memory cache of the operating systems. Modern operating systems (Linux >= 2.4, Windows >=6) will just perform the renaming in their in-memory cache, return to userspace, and then later write it on disk.
3. The speed of the physical disk. In the first case, the *seek speed* is more important than the throughput.
4. The operating system (specifically, its filesystem and block device drivers).
5. The filesystem you've chosen.
6. The programming language (i.e. php vs C) will **not** have any significant impact.

If you want to get specific numbers, just try it. You can measure the time it took with
[getrusage](http://php.net/getrusage).

Answer (score 4):

It will be fast but you can try to put this before your rename :

```
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$starttime = $mtime;
```

and that after your code :

```
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$endtime = $mtime;
$totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
echo "It took ".$totaltime." second(s)";
```

And for PHP5+ you can also use microtime(true) :

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

// Your code

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "It took $time second(s)";
```

But many lines for a rename (you can try to do this with more code if you want to check some things)

Comment: Umm, why don't you use `microtime(true)`? This hole exploding stuff looks really ugly, but that may be my pythonic sense.

Comment: You are right about it, edited my post for PHP5+ versions. Thanks.